# Prevent Sequelize from outputting SQL to the console on execution of query?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a function to retrieve a user's profile.

```
app.get('/api/user/profile', function (request, response)
{
  // Create the default error container
  var error = new Error();

  var User = db.User;
  User.find({
    where: { emailAddress: request.user.username}
  }).then(function(user)
  {
    if(!user)
    {
      error.status = 500; error.message = "ERROR_INVALID_USER"; error.code = 301;
      return next(error);
    }

    // Build the profile from the user object
    profile = {
      "firstName": user.firstName,
      "lastName": user.lastName,
      "emailAddress": user.emailAddress
    }
    response.status(200).send(profile);
  });
});
```

When the "find" function is called it displays the select statement on the console where the server was started.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `emailAddress`, `password`, `passwordRecoveryToken`, `passwordRecoveryTokenExpire`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`emailAddress` = 'johndoe@doe.com' LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a way to get this not to be display?  Some flag that I set in a config file somewhere?

Comment: I have a question, suppose i dont want password field returned in findOrCreate () method. How can i do this ?

Comment: @SunilSharma exclude the attribute, search for `exclude` on this page https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/querying/#attributes

Answer (score 515, accepted):

When you create your Sequelize object, pass `false` to the `logging` parameter:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  
  // disable logging; default: console.log
  logging: false

});
```

For more options, check the [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/getting-started/#logging).

Comment: you are better off starting a new question than trying to piggyback a new question on an barely related one.

Comment: Thank you,this is working however it gives a white space for each query executed. Can you please help me..

Comment: For now, `logging` option should be [a function](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html).

Comment: This doesn't seem to have an effect when using sequelize v4. Anyone found a a resolution?

Comment: getting 404 error on given webpage

Answer (score 57):

If `config/config.json` file is used  then add `"logging": false` to the `config.json` in this case under development configuration section.

```json
// file config/config.json
{
  "development": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "db_name",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "logging": false
  },
  "test": {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 44):

As in other answers, you can just set `logging:false`, but I think better than completely disabling logging, you can just embrace log levels in your app. Sometimes you may want to take a look at the executed queries so it may be better to configure Sequelize to log at level verbose or debug. for example (I'm using winston here as a logging framework but you can use any other framework) :

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  logging: winston.debug
});
```

This will output SQL statements only if winston log level is set to debug or lower debugging levels. If log level is warn or info for example SQL will not be logged

Comment: Is there a way to bit nicely format SQL queries output on terminal? it looks kinda messy especially with those joins

Answer (score 18):

All of these answers are turned off the *logging* at creation time.

But what if we need to turn off the *logging* on runtime ?

By runtime i mean after initializing the `sequelize` object using `new Sequelize(..` function.

I peeked into the [github source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/edac3e9075f9daf70a9ae0681dd4a847db5cbc59/lib/sequelize.js#L240), found a way to turn off logging in runtime.

```
// Somewhere your code, turn off the logging
sequelize.options.logging = false

// Somewhere your code, turn on the logging
sequelize.options.logging = true
```

Comment: very interesting :) this is actually great.. .I will try

Answer (score 6):

Here is my answer:

**Brief**: I was using `typeorm` as a ORM library. So, to set the query logging level I have used the following option instead of directly setting the logging option as `false`.

**Solution:** File name - ormconfig.ts

```
{
    'type': process.env.DB_DRIVER,
    'host': process.env.DB_HOST,
    'port': process.env.DB_PORT,
    'username': process.env.DB_USER,
    'password': process.env.DB_PASS,
    'database': process.env.DB_NAME,
    'migrations': [process.env.MIGRATIONS_ENTITIES],
    'synchronize': false,
    'logging': process.env.DB_QUERY_LEVEL,
    'entities': [
        process.env.ORM_ENTITIES
    ],
    'cli': {
        'migrationsDir': 'migrations'
     }
}
```

And, in the envrionment variable set the `DB_QUERY_LEVEL` as ["query", "error"].

**Result:** As a result it will log only when the query has error else it won't.

**Ref link:** [typeorm db query logging doc](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md)

Hope this helps!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you have logging turned on, you can disable logging on one query by adding 'logging: false' as its option:

```
  User.findAll(
   { where: { emailAddress: request.user.username}
  }, {logging: false}
  )
  .then(function(user)....
```

More info from [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll)

Answer (score 3):

Based on this discussion, I built this `config.json` that works perfectly:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "logging" : false,
    "database": "posts_db_dev",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "operatorsAliases": false 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved a lot of issues by using the following code.
Issues were : -

1. Not connecting with database
2. Database connection Rejection issues
3. Getting rid of logs in console (specific for this).

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("test", "root", "root", {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  dialect: "mysql",
  port: "8889",
  connectionLimit: 10,
  socketPath: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock",
  // It will disable logging
  logging: false
});
```

Comment: people still use MAMP?

Comment: Yes, for development, if you have another best free option, please let me know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using Sequelize ORM 6.0.0 and am using "logging": false as the rest but posted my answer for latest version of the ORM.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
        process.env.databaseName,
        process.env.databaseUser,
        process.env.password,
        {
            host: process.env.databaseHost,
            dialect: process.env.dialect,
            "logging": false,
            define: {
                // Table names won't be pluralized.
                freezeTableName: true,
                // All tables won't have "createdAt" and "updatedAt" Auto fields.
                timestamps: false
            }
        }
    );
```

Note: I am storing my secretes in a configuration file `.env` observing the 12-factor methodology.

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Sequelize({
    host: "localhost",
    database: "database_name",
    dialect: "mysql",
    username: "root",
    password: "password",
    logging: false        // for disable logs
})
```