# Sequelize silent mode

Tags: sequelize.js

How can I make Sequelize ORM silent on logging sql command?

I am using `acl-sequelize` library:

```
var Acl = require('acl');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var AclSeq = require('acl-sequelize');
var db = new Sequelize('mysql://root@localhost:3306/test');   
var acl = new Acl(new AclSeq(db, { prefix: 'acl_' }));
```

How can I make it silent?

Comment: I believe this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28927913

Answer (score 6):

In Options you will need to set logging to false

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db_name', 'user', 'password', {host:host, dialect:"mysql", logging:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the logging option to the Sequelize constructor and set it to false to disable logging SQL commands. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
var Acl = require('acl');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var AclSeq = require('acl-sequelize');
var db = new Sequelize('mysql://root@localhost:3306/test', { logging: false });   
var acl = new Acl(new AclSeq(db, { prefix: 'acl_' }));
```

This will prevent Sequelize from logging SQL commands to the console.