# Sequelize Log Query Without Password

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have sequelize set up to log to winston in the `config.js` file:

```
"mssql": {
        "username": DB_USER,
        "password": DB_PASS,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "dialect": "mssql",
        logging: winston.info
}
```

I want to track all queries that are ran on the server, which is why I turned the logging option on.

However, Sequelize seems to log the username and password in these logs for every executed query.

How can I use sequelize logging, but not output the username and password in the logfile?

Note, there is a related question on how to turn logging off entirely:
[Prevent Sequelize from outputting SQL to the console on execution of query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927836/prevent-sequelize-from-outputting-sql-to-the-console-on-execution-of-query)  I just need to not log the username and password, I do need the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using other then console.log for logging then try setupping logging in sequelize as follows

```
logging: (msg) => logger.trace(msg) // for logger
logging: (msg) => winston.info(msg) // for winston
```

Check this [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7821) for further info.